# Confusion in mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
createTable('messages',
     'id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      auth VARCHAR(16), 
      recip VARCHAR(16),
      pm CHAR(1),
      time INT UNSIGNED, 
      message VARCHAR(4096), 
      INDEX(auth(6)), 
      INDEX(recip(6))');
```

This is a mysql command for creating a table. I was just wondering, what are the last 2 lines of the command, "INDEX(auth(6))" and "INDEX(recip(6))"? I am used to using phpMyAdmin and used to more of the graphical interface. How can you relate this command to the graphical interface process?

Answer (score 0):

In mysql terminal or PHP My admin this is how you can create the table

```
create table messages(
     id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      auth VARCHAR(16), 
      recip VARCHAR(16),
      pm CHAR(1),
      time INT UNSIGNED, 
      message VARCHAR(250), 
      INDEX (auth), 
      INDEX (recip)
);
```

Also note that  `message VARCHAR(4096),` does not make sense since it does not serve any purpose.

[What is the MySQL VARCHAR max size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506832/what-is-the-mysql-varchar-max-size)

The last 2 commands is to create the index on the columns `auth` and `recip`

Here is is what index for http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: Why does `VARCHAR(4096)` not make sense but `VARCHAR(250)` does? That effectively limits the characters that column will hold to ***4096*** does it not?

Comment: @War10ck as per doc Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions. However for  big inputs, its a better idea to use TEXT, MEDIUMTEXTor LONGTEXT instead, and thats my point.

Answer (score 0):

`INDEX(auth(6))` and `INDEX(recip(6))` are included to create indexes on the table. Indexes are created, so that queries (like `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE auth=<xyz>`) would run faster.

The MySQL documentation contains information on [creating indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) as well as [how they are used by MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html).

There is a very detailed explanation of how indexing works in [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work).