# Recommendation on database schema for a text column storing more than 255 characters

Tags: mysql, pdo, database-schema, sqldatatypes

I have a database column that will be storing errors/warnings returned from an API - I would usually have a column called 'description' with a **varchar(255)** but in some (very few cases) this column may need to store a value that is greater than 255 characters (potentially upto 400-500 characters).

This field won't need any ability to search or anything like that, can anyone suggest the best MySQL data type to use for this instance. This will store text and nothing else.

I would presume **text** - but just wondered what everyone else thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use varchar(500) for newer versions.

[What is the MySQL VARCHAR max size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506832/what-is-the-mysql-varchar-max-size)

Comment: ok cool didn't realise this had changed from 255 (thought it would be 255 forever lol)