# PHP echo long text

Tags: php, html

This is inside the phpmyadmin:

[image: This is inside the phpmyadmin]

This is the output after echo:

[image: This is the output after echo]

and this is the code for display output

```
$joinEvent  =   mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM event WHERE event.eventID='".$_GET['eventID']."'");
while($row  =   mysqli_fetch_array($joinEvent))
{
  $joinDetails      =       $row['details'];
}

<p align="justify"><?php echo $joinDetails; ?></p>
```

How do I echo exactly what user enter in the input?

Comment: use `<?php echo nl2br( $joinDetails ); ?>`

Comment: `<?php echo nl2br($joinDetails); ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nl2br()` when you output to the screen, change your current code to:

```
<p align="justify"><?php echo nl2br($joinDetails); ?></p>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be better for you to store your details column as a text datatype. 
Read here: [What is the MySQL VARCHAR max size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506832/what-is-the-mysql-varchar-max-size)

Answer (score 0):

Your result is actually exactly what the user input is ; except that in HTML, line break characters (\r\n \n and so) are not interpreted by the browser. As said in the comments, you'll have to use the PHP function `nl2br()` to convert your line break characters to `<br />` tags, which are the HTML line breaks.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! works like charm