# Json to mariadb triples in storage size

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb, storage, space

I am trying to move my file based organizing json files to mariadb. Approximately there are 2,000,000 json files where in my file based system are zipped. The total storage space for the zipped json files is 7GB.

When i inserted all the records to Mariadb the table storage became 35GB.
i altered my table to be compress and the table size is 15GB.
Is there a way to reduce even more the table size?

Is it normal for the storage to double when data is added to mariadb?

this is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `sbpi_json` (
  `fileid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `json_data` longtext COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `idhash` char(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `sbpi` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `district` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `index_val` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `updated` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;

ALTER TABLE `sbpi_json`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`fileid`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `idhash` (`idhash`),
  ADD KEY `sbpi` (`sbpi`);
```

Comment: What is the encoding of the json files in the file system? What is the updated field? 16GB - is that the space for the data only or does that include the various MySQL log files as well for innodb?

Comment: json files are UTF-8. the updated field is used for on duplicate mysql. the characters for the updated field are less than 10.

Comment: *"Is it normal for the storage to double when data is added to mariadb?"* You can't compare on disk zipped "text" files with innoDB files, both solve different problems... Also you are comparing different compression algorithms... Also in InnoDB you add more columns plus the innoDB engine will add information on how to use/read the records exists and also add records headers.

Comment: The main reason i am making this transfer, from file based to mariadb is due to performance. i used a php script to access the file and echo it to user but i notice there was a big delay (get zip, unzip, find the latest json file and echo it). alternative solution to speed up the process is to move to mariadb but the storage space increased significantly. Any suggestions to minimize the storage size are welcome

Comment: Why didn't you compress the file individually? Then your process would be: find, unzip, echo

Comment: each zip contains a version of each file as also an additional json file with the charcteristict of each version ie date created,hash,index value - the larger the latest. by having a single zip to access and maintain its simplier than having multiple zips.

Comment: @PantelisLivadiotis - Doesn't that mean "unzip old version, add new file, then rezip"?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON column in question is `json_data`, correct?  It averages (uncompressed) about 10KB, correct?  In the file implementation, there are multiple 'versions' of each, correct?  If so, how do you tell which one you want to deliver to the user?

- Most compression techniques give you 3:1; InnoDB compression gives you 2:1.  This is partially because it has things that it can't (or won't) compress.
- Compressing just the JSON column (in client code) and storing it in a `MEDIUMBLOB` will probably take less space in InnoDB than using `COMPRESSED`.  (But this will not be a huge savings.)
- Focus on how you pick which 'version' of the JSON do deliver to the user.  Optimize the schema around that.  Then decide on how to store the data.
- Given that the table can efficiently say which *file* contains the desired JSON, then that will be the best approach.  And use some normal, fast-to-uncompress technique; don't focus on maximal-compression.
- If `char(32) COLLATE utf8_bin` is a hex string, use `ascii`, not `utf8`.
- If it is hex, then `UNHEX` to further shrink it to only `BINARY(16)`.
- When a row is bigger than 8KB, some of the data (probably `json_data`) is stored "off-record".  This implies an extra disk access and disk allocation is a bit more sloppy.  Hence, storing that column as a *file* ends up taking about the same amount of time and space.
- The OS probably allocates space in 4KB chunks.  InnoDB uses 16KB blocks.

Comment: Yes the json_data is the column that significantly increases the storage space. Yes average 10KB. Yes multiple version of each file. The latest is the one to deliver. the hash value is used to compare if there is a change in the file and everytime it changes the index_value increases, therefore the largest index_val is the latest version. I have tried compressing single column and blob datatype but the storage space does not change significantly. I was not expecting for the php zip algorithm to be so different than sql compress

Answer (score -1):

It's the `text` type that takes too much space.
You can try to replace it with [a smaller variant of text type](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/maximum-length-mysql-text-field-types/) if you can give for granted that that much lenght is ok.
Also replacing `char(32)` with `varchar(32)` will help if those values are not always full lenght.

Or you can go with `varchar` even for the textual field, but keep eyes on what's on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506832/what-is-the-mysql-varchar-max-size) before doing so.

Hope I helped!

Comment: I did not downvote, but this answer is incorrect. All of the variable-length types, VARCHAR, VARBINARY, BLOB, TEXT, and all their cousins do not take more space depending on the type. They only store the length of the string value you put into them.

Comment: ι can not reduce to smaller datatype. i tried using text and not longtext and some json data could not be added. the largest detected so far is 2mb uncompress

Comment: Text fields' actual storage requirement is primarily dependant on the data you store in those fields. Just because there is a huge difference in the potential max size of data, it does not mean that there is a big difference if small bits of data are stored in those fields. idhash name indicates that the field will store a hash, which will have a constant length.

Comment: 2MB needs `MEDIUMTEXT`.