# No recordset is returned if one of the column has data more than 1024 characters Mysql 8.0 and Classic ASP

Tags: mysql, vbscript, asp-classic, vb6, adodb

I am using 32 bit MySQL ODBC connector 8.19 with Classic asp
MYSQL server is 8.
CHARACTER is latin1 and COLLATE is latin1_swedish_ci
Connection string has OPTION=3
Storage Engine is InnoDB

Following is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE Data_temp
(
ROWGUID varchar(36) default (UUID()) NOT NULL ,
col_desc varchar(10) NOT NULL ,
History varchar (4000),
PRIMARY KEY Data_temp_P_KEY(ROWGUID)
) ;
```

Using Adodb command run following query

```
Select * from Data_temp WHERE col_desc=?
```

and parameter is supplied by adodb create parameter.

The result is returned in adodb recordset as

```
set recordset=command.execute method
```

recordset is not returned if History column has data more than 1024 characters

If Same query is run in following scenarios
as ,

1. ```
   Select col_desc,Rowguid 
   from Data_temp 
   WHERE col_desc=?
   ```

   i.e. column list do not contain that large data column then recordset is returned
2. ```
   Select col_desc,Rowguid,substring(history,1,1024) 
   from Data_temp 
   WHERE col_desc=?
   ```

   also works.
3. By making column as TEXT data type instead of varchar

What could be the reason?

Is there any limit on returning the column data?
One more observation instead of using parameterised query if query is run directly with value in query itself

```
Select * from Data_temp WHERE Col_Desc='aa'
```

without parameter then recordset is returned

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the MySQL VARCHAR max size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506832/what-is-the-mysql-varchar-max-size)

Comment: @Lankymart this is definitely not a max size issue.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin that's fair enough, I just went off what the OP says - *"recordset is not returned if History column has data more than 1024 characters"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at these similar issues:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92078
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93895
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94545

and the official recommendation:

> Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-odbc/en/news-8-0-16.html
>
> An exception was emitted when fetching contents of a BLOB/TEXT records after executing a statement as a server-side prepared statement with a bound parameter.
>
> The workaround is not using parameters or specifying **NO_SSPS=1** in the connection string; this allows the driver to fetch the data.
>
> In Connector/ODBC 5.2 and after, by default, server-side prepared
> statements are used. When this option is set to a non-zero value,
> prepared statements are emulated on the client side, which is the same
> behavior as in 5.1 and 3.51. Added in 5.2.0.

The recommended workaround is to specify the `NO_SSPS=1` in the connection string and I confirm that it works.

Comment: Thanks @kul-tigin. The `NO_SSPS` connection string setting helped. Thank you so much for the references to the bugs and the documentation for this setting.

Comment: This suggested settings worked. But it generates another problem. The problem is recordset.update fails with error "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done". even if data is small for columns. By changing  recordset.cursorlocation = adUseClient solves the problem. Is this the expected behaviour of that settings ?

Comment: @Anjali I'd expect such behavior. Dealing with MySQL ODBC has always been a problem for me, for almost 20 years. It's like a steaming bug soup and boiling all the time :/