# How to maximize the row size in laravel | mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-design, migration

I want to max the size of the row description. I already set size to 10240 but still it shows error. how to store data in this column because i have to save large amount of data

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('final_news', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('id_newspaper');
        $table->string('heading');
        $table->string('description', 10240);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**ERROR I GET**

```
 SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'description' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `final_news` (`id_newspaper`, `heading`, `d
```

escription`,` updated_at`,` created_at`)

Comment: Change it to `text` type maybe? `$table->text('description');`

Comment: I feel like you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506832/what-is-the-mysql-varchar-max-size

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if string is long you can use longtext

```
  $table->longText('description')
```

The `longText` method creates a `LONGTEXT` equivalent column:

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-longText

Comment: MySQL's `LONGTEXT` has a size limit of 4GB.

Comment: @RickJames.THanks for letting us know