# Save json array in eloquent laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
[
  "module" => "Audio"
  "description" => "2021-08-04/1628067947.39.wav"
  "conversation_id" => null
  "audiotags" => "[{"tag":"Tag some body","id":6,"start":"6.0","end":"6.1","attributes":{"label":"Tag some body"}}]"
]
```

Hello I need to add 'audiotags' column in a table in json format. even try varchar(1000) not saving

sorry for my english

```
$channels_input['audiotags'] = $input['audiotags'];
$channel_data = Channel::create($channels_input);
```

NB: using Mysql8

Comment: VARCHAR max length  is 255. use TEXT (or JSON type on newer versions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: Large VARCHAR vs. TEXT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023481/mysql-large-varchar-vs-text)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506832/what-is-the-mysql-varchar-max-size